# Your DKIM signature is not valid - opendkim

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, dkim, opendkim

I'm running postfix server with few "features" like spf, dmarc and DKIM. SPF and DMARC works fine and when I sent an email to my gmail account I see they PASS, however DKIM shows "FAIL" and I'm not sure why. I used some online-dns checks and they claim that my DKIM DNS record is ok but mail-checks like mail-tester fails:

```
The DKIM signature of your message is:

v=1;
a=rsa-sha256;
c=relaxed/simple;
d=mydomain.com;
s=email;
t=1711628971;
bh=Rv2fKWBlNI8YfmXfYIWLRt8FRQfzmecyWP3jcdyv3KQ=;
h=Subject:From:To;


b=Euf/WOxr4EcUxl3MgvTfpod7gkhQ8MPsxm8qULS2lD83fx1PWPeVaB+JTQJk27bQNzXPZcufpB0ANcA3hG34WDzKCefabN/Y97OdyRoI6nAH4JfeXqG3AeloDDc6i6o1961TLNVZr8qjPBe2quQSb+LPY/EpGu1RSRxgQO9ws/Yv92IHV6Lx8tzcQjDKQ3CAkTV+v9FGxp3l/VJDbbUbCU9P/8WuQ1JjluP4zJSJPV9zd6EWRiJgiLomXSlaSI5ekvbJRip1uLFfq8Qr7sXcmlW3mCts3bkS95LU8kFJ8/27TXzJY32sVw2tkX0h9Hx/6YUVOjlbGI590JJ/IsCoIg==
Your public key is:

"v=DKIM1;
k=rsa;
p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA24F81SHRpZJ/EA3NAfWRYEwKi6XHx1o/RIGVDuEMvxefDDOtbRQsh4hG7er/Ll3f4ID4aTa99IHWHx/Zik0PBnXwDLbGqDqqU0dgtURYGfRXwuxtvvQfuOaWLa9DwVKiIUOcPtXIdh6a5sM73jQcatCaPwoVZadVb9klQubN+NU3A7JI1FtIk0Lovm7gOr/7VSuibcV6Ni8ZZ/5jM4xo67LpT3rbJpDsmKWRFoe1HmU3pe2+AmG/hFnOvLHkGYt6j0gdHJbIUdjr/ObBzQJ8VSFQJY55ortYMFxR1LO79f5G1CT3bMlLMauH2odzPTSGBeP7ihlP3zFblFd6MOKmrwIDAQAB"
Key length: 2048bits

Your DKIM signature is not valid
```

**File: opendkim.conf:**

```
root@email:/# cat /etc/opendkim.conf 
AutoRestart             Yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1h
UMask                   002
Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           Yes
LogWhy                  Yes
RemoveOldSignatures     Yes

Canonicalization        relaxed/simple

ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/truhost
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/truhost
KeyTable                /etc/opendkim/keyt
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/sign

Mode                    sv
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256

UserID                  opendkim:opendkim

Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
OmitHeaders             Message-ID, Date, Return-Path, Bounces-To, Received, Comments, 

Keywords, Bcc, Resent-Bcc, List-ID, List-Unsubscribe, DKIM-Signature<Paste>
    Nameservers 127.0.0.11
```

**File keyt:**

```
email._domainkey.mydomain.com mydomain.com:email:/etc/opendkim/keys/mydomain.com/email.private
```

**File: sign:**

```
*@mydomain.com email._domainkey.mydomain.com
```

One website mentioned:
Validating Signature

result = fail
Details: bad RSA signature

I took my DKIM record from email.txt as opendkim generate it automatically and it looks like this:

```
"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; "
"p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1MjR9CMslFUjbjDA7XWVFCcVOS6nVruC9iILNrSAMoozGgqOxp0vCBOFtCmdpVl/AK66wzo6WiCDyO1MqL0r+EKZbHSoSGurQRuq1FTcSDB110gfuyB/EwoAmW1z8YiK5dU7ae/rrpZH5IHr18F/cnMSX6UvjhO52qOkru06YkxXVnunZQ3zsOntpLJgLZ6f3bSbkv1R72/n+A"
    "ObOYzx3ZB0j7pUPc4b3NzPycQKd/gIN72GPWixy5RkaKBqc89MR71MfefzmLA2cyedORp0xayMAZRJxD6BA1hLjXJ1DDdufL5rJIIU/R5s2jCWawAXK4Sw+wepsQRfYQra0605EwIDAQAB"
```

It was failing when I was trying to add it in dns and I had to remove "" after n+A and replace it with / then it worked
I'm running out of ideas why it doesn't work

Comment: If the signature fails to validate, it means that headers and/or body were modified. Find out why your message is being modified. With the info given here (no real domain, no real message) there is not much anyone can say.

Comment: Did you notice that the public key in the mail-tester.com output differs from the public key in the email.txt you provided? Could it be possible that you've added the wrong key to your domain's DNS records?